# Swift firebase "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBDescriptor" error

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification

I import `firebase` manually

On run get below error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBDescriptor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseMessaging(GtalkCore.pbobjc.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseMessaging(GtalkExtensions.pbobjc.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBCodedOutputStream", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseMessaging(FIRMessagingSecureSocket.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBFileDescriptor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseMessaging(GtalkCore.pbobjc.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseMessaging(GtalkExtensions.pbobjc.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRInstanceID", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseMessaging(FIRMessaging.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPBMessage", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkHeartbeatPing in FirebaseMessaging(GtalkCore.pbobjc.o)
```

...
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Also, I added `libz,libsqlite3,libc++` and `libcucore`

In `AppDelegate` I added `FirebaseApp.configure()`

Answer (score 6):

Mainly if you are going to use `FirebaseMessaging.framework` you will need a combination of different frameworks with it. **Without them you will have linker errors**.

> ```
> Firebase.framework
> FirebaseCore.framework
> FirebaseInstanceID.framework
> GoogleUtilities.framework
> Protobuf.framework
> ```

Nothing else. No need for all of these `libz`,`libsqlite3`,`libc++` and `libcucore`